# Cannot install numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I am new to Python. I am trying to install numpy but every time I got this error.

```
C:\Users\Tech Land>pip3 install numpy
Collecting numpy
  Using cached numpy-1.19.2.zip (7.3 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
    Preparing wheel metadata ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\users\tech land\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\python.exe' 'c:\users\tech land\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\_in_process.py' prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel 'C:\Users\TECHLA~1\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpkjezpsa7'
         cwd: C:\Users\Tech Land\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-zjon8mw3\numpy
    Complete output (200 lines):
    Running from numpy source directory.
    setup.py:470: UserWarning: Unrecognized setuptools command, proceeding with generating Cython sources and expanding templates
      run_build = parse_setuppy_commands()
    Processing numpy/random\_bounded_integers.pxd.in
    Processing numpy/random\bit_generator.pyx
    Processing numpy/random\mtrand.pyx
    Processing numpy/random\_bounded_integers.pyx.in
    Processing numpy/random\_common.pyx
    Processing numpy/random\_generator.pyx
    Processing numpy/random\_mt19937.pyx
    Processing numpy/random\_pcg64.pyx
    Processing numpy/random\_philox.pyx
    Processing numpy/random\_sfc64.pyx
    Cythonizing sources
    blas_opt_info:
    blas_mkl_info:
    No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
    customize MSVCCompiler
      libraries mkl_rt not found in ['c:\\users\\tech land\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\lib', 'C:\\', 'c:\\users\\tech land\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\libs']
      NOT AVAILABLE
```

can anyone tell me whats the problem is? I am using Python 3.9.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
pip3 install wheel
```

Could you try to reinstall it after executing this command?

Comment: i gave pip3 install numpy. wheel means?

Comment: Wheel is a package format. Try to install wheel first, then try to install numpy. If that doesn't solve your problem let me know.

Comment: I installed wheel .but after installing it when I tried two install numpy I got this same error

Comment: https://www.python.org/downloads/windows/

Go to this page and download python interpreter that is compatible with your system If your system is 64 bit download x86-64, else x86

Comment: I know. But try to install the compatible one with your system. That error may occur because your system is not compatible with the python interpreter you installed. If your system is 64 bit install x86-64, else x86.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223061/discussion-between-sanzida-sultana-and-artoria).

Comment: I downloaded python 3.8.6 now I can able to install numpy.thanks

Answer (score 1):

Last I heard, numpy was not yet available for Python 3.9, so pip wants to build it instead of just installing precompiled binary code.

You might want to check if numpy is prebuilt for 3.9 yet, and if not, switch to Python 3.8.

Comment: I downloaded python 3.8.6 now I can able to install numpy.thanks

Answer (score 0):

Installing on windows can sometimes be tricky. The error says it can't find 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils and also it cannot find mkl_rt liabrary in your declared paths.
You can download and install them separately and then try to install numpy again.
usually, there are different files for 32 and 64 bit systems so choose the one which fits you.